# Python nested dictonaries

Tags: python-2.7

```
{'140508921-1183337': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': nan,
  'HARDWARE_PILLAR': nan,
  'SECURITY_PILLAR': nan,
  'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': nan},
 'PSS_13240-1451364': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': 10.0,
  'HARDWARE_PILLAR': 25.0,
  'SECURITY_PILLAR': 55.0,
  'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': 10.0}
}
```

want to remove keys which has nan values .
such as '140508921-1183337''should be removed as its keys/values pairs null

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is the dictionary do this:

```
a={'140508921-1183337': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': 'nan', 'HARDWARE_PILLAR': 'nan', 'SECURITY_PILLAR':'nan', 'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': 'nan'}, 'PSS_13240-1451364': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': 10.0, 'HARDWARE_PILLAR': 25.0, 'SECURITY_PILLAR': 55.0, 'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': 10.0}}


def remove_keys_with_nan(item):
    if not hasattr(item, 'items'):
        return item
    else:
        d = {key: remove_keys_with_nan(value) for key, value in item.iteritems() if value is not 'nan'}
        return dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v)

a = remove_keys_with_nan(a)

print(a)
```

**Result:**

```
{'PSS_13240-1451364': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': 10.0, 'HARDWARE_PILLAR': 25.0, 'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': 10.0, 'SECURITY_PILLAR': 55.0}}
```

**EDIT-new answer to your new question**

use:

```
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan

a={'140508921-1183337': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': nan, 'HARDWARE_PILLAR': nan, 'SECURITY_PILLAR': nan, 'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': nan}, 'PSS_13240-1451364': {'COVERAGE_PILLAR': 10.0, 'HARDWARE_PILLAR': 25.0, 'SECURITY_PILLAR': 55.0, 'SOFTWARE_PILLAR': 10.0}}
```

and then the same code as previously.

Comment: need to remove '''140508921-1183337': {}'this also from the dict.

Comment: @SoravVerma ohh. right. let me edit my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Still getting same dict i.e result did not change. pasting code and output below:

Comment: def remove_keys_with_nan(item):
    if not hasattr(item, 'items'):
        return item
    else:
        d = {key: remove_keys_with_nan(value) for key, value in item.iteritems() if value is not 'nan'}
        return dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v)

d1 = remove_keys_with_nan(d1)

print(d1)

Comment: I guess you do not use the right indentation. I added a link with the code. Download the file and run from terminal like: python d.py. Also, do you use python 2.x or 3.x ???

Comment: Thank you for all the help.. i am new to python but i think indentation is ok..I think, It is not able to capture 'nan' values

Comment: If you look at the dictionary a that I create , I put 'nan' . In your original post, you have simply: nan. Try to use as dictionary values : 'nan' using the ' ' characters

Comment: Ok. I get it..but I am getting nan only in the data field.How to solve that?

Comment: What do you mean in the data field? Can you explain more ? Also, when I try to create a dictionary using the dictionary from your original post I get error: nan is not define . So you need to use 'nan' as values and not simply nan

Comment: I originally had a dataframe which has nan values..through that i have created 3 dictonary.. now i need to remove all the key values if it has nan values across it.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I replaced nan values to '' at the time importing data..an your code worked..Thank u again..!!

Comment: glad that I could help. You can accept the answer as accepted if you do not mind

Comment: I have edited my response.. Can u pls and let me know how to solve it..Thanks..Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SoravVerma this time you have nan as values ?

Comment: No, i have replaced the with blank ('') as the time of data import